CocoaMQTT(error): The deliver delegate is nil!!! the frame will be drop:
I am trying to connect to MQTT broker, in very simple steps, but I am getting error CocoaMQTT(error): The deliver delegate is nil!!! the frame will be drop:PUBLISH(id: 2, topic: your-topic, payload: [72, 101, 108,...]
I have create one class as:
import Foundation
import CocoaMQTT

class MQTTManager: CocoaMQTTDelegate {
    var mqtt: CocoaMQTT!
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
      print("Published message with ID: \(id)")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopics success: NSDictionary, failed: [String]) {  print("Subscribed to topics: \(success)") }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopics topics: [String]) { print("Unsubscribed from topics: \(topics)")  }
    
    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) { print("Pinged!") }
    
    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) { print("Ponged!") }
    
    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: (any Error)?) { print("Disconnected from the MQTT")  }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        if ack == .accept {
            print("Connected to the MQTT!")
        } else {
            print("Failed to connect to MQTT")
        }
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        print("Data published successfully")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        if let messageString = message.string {
            print("Received message on topic \(message.topic): \(messageString)")
        }
    }

    func connectMQTT() {
        mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "broker.hivemq.com"", host: "your-client-id-435345", port: 1883)
        //tried with CocoaMQTT.init(clientID: "broker.hivemq.com"", host: "your-client-id-435345", port: 1883)
        mqtt.delegate = self
        mqtt.connect()
    }
    func subscribeToTopic(topic: String) {
        mqtt.subscribe(topic)
    }
    func publishData(topic: String, message: String) {
        mqtt.publish(topic, withString: message, qos: .qos1)
    }
}


I am trying to use it in function as:
   @objc(sendTelemetryMsg:withUrl:withResolver:withRejecter:)
    func sendTelemetryMsg(password: String, url: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
        
    let mqttManager = MQTTManager();
     mqttManager.connectMQTT()

        // Subscribe to a topic
        let topic = "your-topic"
        mqttManager.subscribeToTopic(topic: topic)

        // Publish data to the IoT device
        let message = "Hello, IoT Device!"
        mqttManager.publishData(topic: topic, message: message)
    }



import Foundation
import CocoaMQTT

class MQTTManager: CocoaMQTTDelegate {
    var mqtt: CocoaMQTT!

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
        print("Published message with ID: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopics success: NSDictionary, failed: [String]) {
        print("Subscribed to topics: \(success)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopics topics: [String]) {
        print("Unsubscribed from topics: \(topics)")
    }

    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("Pinged!")
    }

    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("Ponged!")
    }

    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: (Error?)?) {
        print("Disconnected from MQTT, error: \(String(describing: err))")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        if ack == .accept {
            print("Connected to the MQTT broker!")
            // Subscribe to a topic only after a successful connection
            subscribeToTopic(topic: "your-topic")
        } else {
            print("Failed to connect to MQTT")
        }
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        print("Published message: \(message.string ?? "") with ID: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        if let messageString = message.string {
            print("Received message on topic \(message.topic): \(messageString)")
        }
    }

    func connectMQTT() {
        mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "unique-client-id", host: "broker-address-or-ip", port: 1883)
        mqtt.delegate = self
        mqtt.connect()
    }

    func subscribeToTopic(topic: String) {
        mqtt.subscribe(topic, qos: .qos1)  // Ensure you're using proper QoS
        print("Attempting to subscribe to topic: \(topic)")
    }

    func publishData(topic: String, message: String) {
        mqtt.publish(topic, withString: message, qos: .qos1)
        print("Publishing message: \(message) to topic: \(topic)")
    }
}

and also
@objc(sendTelemetryMsg:withUrl:withResolver:withRejecter:)
func sendTelemetryMsg(password: String, url: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    let mqttManager = MQTTManager()
    mqttManager.connectMQTT()

    // You can remove these calls from here, as you should subscribe/publish after connecting.
    // mqttManager.subscribeToTopic(topic: "your-topic")
    // mqttManager.publishData(topic: "your-topic", message: "Hello, IoT Device!")
}

do not forget to set
mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "unique-client-id", host: "your-broker-url-or-ip", port: 1883)


Hi @Emrecan, Thank you for you response. But I didn't understand the changes here, because still its not working for me.

Fix it by adding
let mqttManager = MQTTManager();
in class level as well, referring to this
